# Paint.net do you get a save for web plugin?

Tags: paint.net

I've noticed there are lots of plugins for Paint.net, but I can't seem to find one that essentially saves for web, almost like Photoshop does this.

Let me explain:

Lets say you have a large image. Photoshop has the ability to resize this image and adjust the resolution / dpi all in 1 easy step. this way you end up with excellent file sizes after the resize without doing this resizing manually.

Please post if you know of such a plugin, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) has a *Save For Web* option.  You will need to download the plugins from their website (individually, or in one large .exe).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, Paint.net might not be the app I want to go for, instead I downloaded Artweaver, and besides being a better overall product in my opinion to Paint.net, it also is more geared towards modern productivity tasks - like save for web.

Comment: Art weaver comes with its own problems. It looks good on the surface, but its full of bugs.

Answer (score -2):

To save for use in web browsers, simply save to JPEG (usually .jpg), GIF or PNG format (resizing first if required).

What extra work does the Photoshop plugin do that you would like to see in a Paint.net plugin? (bare in mind there might be quite a number of people here who use Paint.net a lot but are not overly familiar with PS, so "like Photoshop" needs to be expanded a bit).

Comment: I would not call this an answer, more of a comment.

I think the OP might be referring to a special dialog that shows the possible file size for each format (.gif / .png / .jpg) given a certain quality rating.  Or something...

Comment: -1 This is exactly why I want the plugin, to save me additional steps. Its not as simple as resizing then save, you also need to adjust the resolution if you're optimizing for thumbnails, etc.

Comment: @Scott: aye, that probably should have been a comment. 
@JL: "this is exactly why I want the plugin"... then that should have been included in your question. Ask good questions with all pertinant details and you are more likely to get good answers.

Comment: It was a fine question, if you were unfamiliar with the dialog he's talking about then you should just wait for someone who is to answer the question.